# Shift up a title in beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

I have been trying to shift a title up in `beamer` but I couldn't. I have tried with `\vspace` but it is not useful here, as you can check..
I have read all similar posts but no one was helpful for me.

Here is a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\begin{document}
\title{Thermodynamics applied to microscopic phenomena using a computational-quantum mechanics approach}
\institute{{\large University of Maryland}\\~\\
    {\small Faculty of sciences}}
\author[Hermann]{Hermann Hesse}
\date{2017}

\titlepage
\end{document}
```

Any help will be well received.

Comment: I wasn't aware that [Hermann Hesse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Hesse) was a member of the U. of Maryland... :P

Comment: :) @Narusan.......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `\vspace{...}`:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}

\begin{document}
\title{Thermodynamics applied to microscopic phenomena using a computational-quantum mechanics approach}
\institute{{\large University of Maryland}\\~\\
    {\small Faculty of sciences}}
\author[Hermann]{Hermann Hesse}
\date{2017}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace{-2cm}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, damn..i though `vspace` should be after "title". Thank you so much..

Comment: @HernanProust: Accepting **and** upvoting is the proper way to say `thank you` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, i was fighting with the document but i know how it works. Thanks..upvote to your comment